# Select from array in postgresql to get all possible results

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

im using postgresql 11.2 on a docker container and im trying to get data on this column that containes arrays "event_type" :

```
   event_type
-----------------
 {ERROR}
 {INFO}
 {ERROR,VERBOSE}
 {ERROR,VERBOSE}
 {INFO,NOTIFY}
```

event_type column schema :

```
event_type | text[]
```

Selecting all rows which contained 'ERROR': (works fine)

```
 SELECT event_type FROM events WHERE event_type @> ARRAY['ERROR'];
   event_type
-----------------
 {ERROR}
 {ERROR,VERBOSE}
 {ERROR,VERBOSE}
(3 rows)
```

If i want to get all rows which contained 'ERROR' AND \ OR ' NOTIFY' :

```
 SELECT event_type FROM events WHERE event_type @> ARRAY['ERROR', 'NOTIFY'];
 event_type
------------
(0 rows)
```

The desired response would be :

```
   event_type
-----------------
 {ERROR}
 {ERROR,VERBOSE}
 {ERROR,VERBOSE}
 {INFO,NOTIFY}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use overlap operator `&&`

```
SELECT event_type FROM events WHERE event_type && ARRAY['ERROR', 'NOTIFY'];
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html